# Android - What causes buggy layout on a real device, while on emulator it worked correctly?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have only one button in my layout which covers the whole screen (both height and width are match_parent).

But the button is not clickable everywhere. There is a rectangle(or an area) in the middle which is unclickable, so the button is only touchable on the edges of the screen. This certain layout is for a fragment. The fragment is in a ViewPager as the main screen with another one, which works properly.

I'm desperate, I replaced my complex source code and my xml, to get rid of the bug, but it still exists. What should I check? What are the possible reasons why the bug only shows up in a real device, and in the emulator works correctly? Frankly I don't even know which code should I attach..

Comment: Attach your xml containing your button/rectangle and the code for your onClick functionality. Past that there shouldn't be much we need to see.

Comment: There is no OnClick method for that button, I selected the default style, because it indicates click with blue flash. And this unclickable area (aka rectangle) shows up unintentionally. Sorry for not being meticulous.

Comment: Ohhh so the item is supposed to be clickable everywhere and it isn't? Can you post your xml?

Comment: Exactly! Tomorrow I will be able to post my codes. But I am almost sure that this is Android Studio's bug. Anyway, thanks for the reply.